# codeigniter language changes + database interaction

Tags: codeigniter

I've found alot of questions like this one around the site but none of them seem to be exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm using a pre_controller hook to change the config language option.

```
    function get_language(){

        session_start();

        if($this->ci->session->userdata('language')){

            if($_SESSION['language']){
                $language = $_SESSION['language'];

                // Load CI config class
                $CI_config =& load_class('Config');

                // Set the language config. Selects the folder name from its key of 'en'
                $CI_config->set_item('language', $language);

                // Sets a constant to use throughout ALL of CI.
                define('CURRENT_LANGUAGE', $language);
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine but I'd like to access the CI object as well.. I know that because the hook is pre controller that won't work. However if I make the hook post_controller_constructor the language change doesn't work because it's already all been loaded using the default language option.

I can do what I want in the hook using standard php but I would be happier to use the CI Object.

I think this is probably do able and I'm just missing something or doing something wrong.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create My_Controller, Create MY_Controller and add in a custom hook point:

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller {

function MY_Controller()
{
    parent::Controller();
    $GLOBALS['EXT']->_call_hook('pre_controller_constructor');
} 

}
```

Hope it helps